# CXF - Cannot Add Feature

Tags: java, eclipse, cxf

I have been using Apache CXF 2.7.0 for quite a while now, but recently I had to restructure my project in Eclipse. After I did that, for some reason, I cannot add a "WSAddressingFeature" Feature to the endpoint.

What am I missing??

```
    endpoint.getFeatures().add(new org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.WSAddressingFeature());
```

Eclipse is reporting that:

```
"The method add(Feature) in the type List<Feature> is not applicable for the arguments (WSAddressingFeature)"
```

This is my full implementation:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:" + m_Port + "/infoburst/handler";
    Object implementor = new HandlerImpl();
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl endpoint = new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl(implementor);
    endpoint.getFeatures().add(new org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.WSAddressingFeature());
    endpoint.publish(url);

    org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server server = endpoint.getServer();
    org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean serverFB = endpoint.getServerFactory();
```

If I remove the line of code that adds the feature, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.bindOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:276)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createOperation(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:1045)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.createOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:642)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.createInterface(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:990)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:481)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:704)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:155)
at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Unknown Source)
at com.infosol.infoburst.XI4Service.HandlerService.publish(HandlerService.java:106)
at com.infosol.infoburst.XI4Service.HandlerService.main(HandlerService.java:42)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is why I really don't enjoy working in the Java environment...

To fix the ""The method add(Feature) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (WSAddressingFeature)" error:

1. Go into "Configure Build Path"
2. Go to "Order and Export"
3. Move the "cfx-2.7.0.jar" file to a higher priority, this may take a little trial and error.

Once the CFX file is moved up in priority, the error will go away.